# Data in Tkinter not updating when running SQLite3 delete from

Tags: python, function, sqlite, tkinter

Alrighty, so I have 3 total functions defined in the project, but when I use the delete command, it will not refresh the other function to show the update to the rows, but when I use the submit command it does refresh. Any Advice? Main goal is that first my_delete(), I included the submit() as that one is correctly updating the show().

###### Little function to clearly pull information from the database for active trades, seperating the proper information to the columns and rows

```
def my_delete(self,id):
    my_var=tkinter.messagebox.askyesnocancel("DELETE?", "Delete id:"+str(id),icon='warning',default="no")
    if my_var:
        r_set=c.execute("DELETE FROM openPositions WHERE s_id=" + str(id) )
        conn.commit()
        tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Deleted ","No of records deleted=" +str(r_set.rowcount))
        self.show()
        
def show(self):
    r_set=c.execute("SELECT * FROM openPositions")
    i=6
    for openPositions in r_set:
        for j in range(len(openPositions)):
            e = Label(self.master, width=10, text=(openPositions[j]), font=("Helvetica", 12))
            e.grid(row=i, column = j + 1, padx=(70,0), pady=(5,0), columnspan=1)
                ### Close position button to populate for every trade ### 
        e = Button(self.master, text="Close Position", width=30, command=lambda d=openPositions[0] : self.my_delete(d))
        e.grid(row=i, column = 6, padx=(10,0), pady=(5,0), columnspan=3)
        
        i=i+1 # increments for each to next row


### Function for when Button is Pressed ###    
def submit(self):
    ### convert string values to a new variable ##
    stk = self.varStk.get()
    typ = self.varType.get()
        ## changing quan and etrPr from string to integer and float values for multiplication ##
    quan = int(self.varQuan.get())
    entPr = float(self.varEnPr.get())
        ## multiplying quan and entPr to give us the Position Size for database and submitted text ##
    posSize = quan * entPr
        ## Clearing entered data and resetting drop down menu to buy once button is clicked ##
    self.txtStkTik.delete(0, END)
    self.txtpos_quan.delete(0, END)
    self.txtpos_price.delete(0, END)
    self.varType.set("Buy")
        ## setting variables into an array for easy submitting to database ##
    array1 = [stk,typ,quan,entPr,posSize]
        ## connecto to database and inserting array of variables into database ##
    conn.executemany('INSERT INTO openPositions(stock_ticker, entryType, pos_quan, entryPrice, pos_size) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', (array1,))
    conn.commit()
        ## pop up message displaying that commit of stock was completed ##
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Trade Submitted.", "You submitted {} for {} order in amount of {} share at an entry price of ${} for a total Position Size of ${}".format(stk,typ,quan,entPr,posSize))

        #### Copied over the function for writing the information on screen to auto populate info when clicking submit instead of refreshing the app ###
    self.show()
```

Comment: You need to clear currently shown records before populating new records inside `show()`.

Comment: How do i go about doing that?